# Image of an open set has measure zero under a smooth map

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that, if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an open set, and $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map, with $m<n$, then $F(U)$ has measure zero? (In the sense that the set can be covered by countable many open cubes with volume as small as desired). It seems to me that $U$ should have measure zero for this result make sense.

Comment: $U$ doesn't need to have measure zero on $\mathbb R^m$. Consider for example $m=1$, $n=2$, $U=\mathbb R$ and $F(x)=(x,0)$.

Comment: To add to what Henning Makholm said, in fact the only open set of measure zero is the emptyset.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is true for any open set $U$, and it's actually very simple.

Since a countable union of sets of measure zero has measure zero it's enough to show that $F(K)$ has measure zero for any compact $K\subset U$. Now for any $r>0$ there exist $N \le cr^{-m}$ balls $B_j=B(x_j,r)$ with $$K\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^NB(x_j,r).$$Since $F$ is smooth there exists $\alpha$ so that $$F(B_j)\subset B(F(x_j),\alpha r).$$

So $F(K)\subset\bigcup B(F(x_j),\alpha r)$, and hence the Lebesgue measure of $F(K)$ is no larger than $$c\sum_{j=1}^N(\alpha r)^n\le c\alpha^nr^{n-m}.$$Since $n>m$, letting $r\to0$ shows that $F(K)$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has zero measure. It is straight application of the [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem).